# Change Ext.js TreePanel checkbox element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, extjs

I have basic treepanel checkbox example from Ext.js like this :

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        renderTo:'tree-div',
        title: 'My Task List',
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        useArrows:true,
        autoScroll:true,
        animate:true,
        enableDD:true,
        containerScroll: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        frame: true,
        root: {
            nodeType: 'async'
        },

        // auto create TreeLoader
        dataUrl: 'check-nodes.json',

        listeners: {
            'checkchange': function(node, checked){
                if(checked){
                    node.getUI().addClass('complete');
                }else{
                    node.getUI().removeClass('complete');
                }
            }
        },

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Get Completed Tasks',
            handler: function(){
                var msg = '', selNodes = tree.getChecked();
                Ext.each(selNodes, function(node){
                    if(msg.length > 0){
                        msg += ', ';
                    }
                    msg += node.text;
                });
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: 'Completed Tasks', 
                    msg: msg.length > 0 ? msg : 'None',
                    icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                    minWidth: 200,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }]
    });

    tree.getRootNode().expand(true);
});
```

And this is for check-nodes.json:

```
[{
    text: 'To Do', 
    cls: 'folder',
    children: [{
        text: 'Go jogging',
        id: 'test',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    },{
        text: 'Take a nap',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    },{
        text: 'Climb Everest',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    }]
}]
```

So Ext.js will try to translate those json data to html input checkbox like this:
[image]

Is there any way to change the ID of input checkbox?
I tried to set the key Id at json file "id:test" but it return the html script like this:
[image]
Something effected on it "ext:tree-node-id=test", all i need is to set something like this
"`<input class="x-tree-node-cb" type="checkbox" id="test">`"
Is there any way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change the input checkbox to this:

xtype: 'checkbox', 
id: 'hidetypecheckbox',

Regards 
MH